# How does one implement Prisma's tracing preview feature when using Datadog?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma, datadog, open-telemetry

I am trying to have Prisma's telemetry data show up in Datadog and its traces, but I can't seem to configure both properly. I have added `previewFeatures = ["tracing"]` to my Prisma schema, and this snippet to my app's startup:

```
const tracer = ddTrace.init();
const { TracerProvider } = tracer;
const provider = new TracerProvider();

registerInstrumentations({
  tracerProvider: provider,
  instrumentations: [new PrismaInstrumentation()],
});

provider.register();
```

But it's not doing the trick. Currently, we use the node args approach to initialize tracing, and it works perfectly with express telemetry (Since it's a NestJS app), but I cannot seem to be able to add Prisma to that. There is also no plugin in dd-trace for prisma, and the middleware approach of manually tracing queries is now deprecated by Prisma - not that we ever used it.

What am I missing?

EDIT: Tried importing from `dd-trace/init` and having that be the first import, while removing the init call further below and it didn't work either

EDIT 2: After a bit of tinkering, we found a partial solution in https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-js/issues/1244. Long story short, Prisma's OpenTelemetry implementation isn't 100% compatible with Datadog's implementation given the trace and span ID formats, so some conversion is required. We are now seeing Prisma's client's traces, which is good enough for us (at least for now) - although we're missing deeper traces from the engine and whatnot. Within the linked issues, there's a listed solution for that, but it did not work for us (granted, we had a similar solution implemented before for the duplicity of Prisma clients)